# How many primitive polynomials are there in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ where $p$ is prime?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I've read the post [The number of primitive polynomials of degree $m$ over a finite field $GF(p^m)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670710/the-number-of-primitive-polynomials-of-degree-m-over-a-finite-field-gfpm), but I don't understand why there can't be common roots of distinct primitive polynomials of the same degree. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: The extension $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is neither finite dimension, nor an extension of fields... you should probably alter that title

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Sorry, I'll edit it.

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^\times$ is cyclic generated by $g$ then the degree $n$ primitive polynomials $\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ are the $f_l(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x-g^{l p^k})$ for $l$ coprime with $p^n-1$. Then $f_l = f_m$ iff $m=l p^k\bmod p^n-1$ for some $k< n-1$,  that makes $\phi(p^n-1)/n$ such polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

- Primitive polynomials are irreducible
- If two polynomials $f, g$ have roots in common, then $\gcd(f, g)\neq 1$

Couple these two facts together, and you get that two primitive polynomials with any roots in common must have *all* their roots in common.

---

Somewhat alternate reasoning (and the one hinted at in the linked post):

Given a primitive polynomial $f$ over $\Bbb F_p$, extending $\Bbb F_p$ by any of the roots of $f$ gives $\Bbb F_{p^m}$. Given another primitive polynomial $g$ of the same degree, any one of its roots generates the same (or at least an isomorphic) field.

If $f$ and $g$ have roots in common, then $h = \gcd(f, g)$ will also have those roots in common. And thus any root of $h$ will also generate $\Bbb F_{p^m}$. But that's a degree $m$ extension, so $h$ must have degree $m$. Thus $\gcd(f, g)$ has the same degree as $f$ and $g$, so $f$ and $g$ are (up to multiplication by a constant) the same polynomial.

Comment: But those roots are in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ while $f,g$ are in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Is it possible that $f,g$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ but have common factors in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}[x]$?

Comment: @atlantic0cean The second bullet point of my answer doesn't care that the roots they share live outside of the field the polynomials are defined over. For any field $K$, if $f, g\in K[x]$ have roots in common in the algebraic closure of $K$, then $\gcd(f, g)\in K[x]$ also has those same roots in the closure of $K$, and can therefore not be $1$.

Comment: I think I get it!  Thank you for your patience!